# Is there any way to download the AAB(Android App Bundle) version of an Android application?

Tags: android

Google said from August 2021, new apps will be required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. I want to know the difference between a specific application on different devices, so I need the AAB(Android App Bundle) version of the application. Is there any way to download the AAB version of the Android application?

Comment: Do you want to generate AAB file or do you want to download the AAB file from play store after you uploaded ?

Comment: I mean if I am interested in the differences between an application on different devices, is there any way to download the AAB version of that application? Not to generate AAB files, but to get AAB files of a certain application.